# GRUB complains of "no such partition" after installing 12:04

Tags: 12.04, grub2, system-installation

I have just installed 12.04.  I previously had 11.10 installed, with `/dev/sda6` as the install partition mounted at `/` and with `/dev/sda1` mounted at `/home`.  When installing 12.04, I duly selected the same options, with no reformatting.  I selected `/dev/sda6` as the bootloader partition.  I was warned, as expected, that the system files on `/dev/sda6` would be deleted.

After reinstalling, I can't get past GRUB: selecting the main boot option, or the recovery mode option, both give me the error "No such partition", and the option to go back to the main GRUB screen.

What's going on here?  What partition is it saying doesn't exist?  And obviously, how do I fix this?

---

Edit 1:

I get the error three times; it looks like:

```
error: no such partition.
error: no such partition.
error: no such partition.

Press any key to continue ...
```

This also happens with the "Memory test" boot options.

Entering the command line and running `ls` gives me the same error.

Comment: Glad that I am not the only one! https://plus.google.com/103621378732713508804/posts/i7ddQoUXJ52

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To repair the Grub bootloader, try these steps.

### 1 - Live CD

First, you'll need to boot from a Ubuntu Live CD.

### 2 - Repair the bootloader

Open a terminal from the Live CD, and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

After a few seconds, Boot Repair's main window will open.

Click on `Recommended repair`.

### You're done!

Reboot to test everything out.

If everything went well, you should be up and running now. If not, keep going.

### Command-line version

If the above fails, you can also use the command line (from a Live CD) to reinstall Grub.

**Important:** Replace `sda1` with the partiton that contains Ubuntu and `sda` with the drive that contains Ubuntu's partition

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda
*edit* at this point, also ensure that if /usr and /var are on seperate partitions that you mount them to /mnt/usr and /mnt/var
*edit 2* whithin the chroot you need to have /dev /run and /proc available for update-grub to work, use the following to acheive that: for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
sudo chroot /mnt
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I tried this and it got stuck forever (30 minutes) on a `dpkg` command.  However I did get this Boot Info Summary: http://paste.ubuntu.com/947723/

Comment: Ok, then based on the Boot Info script's output, you could try running (from the Live CD): `sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt && sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda && sudo chroot /mnt && sudo update-grub && sudo reboot`

Comment: IT WORKS!  Seriously, thanks.  And I shall continue with my head in the sand when it comes to the complexities of bootloaders ...

Comment: Good! I'm glad it worked! I'll update my answer to help others who could have your problem..

Comment: Thanks a lot .. really it does great.. Now i can log on Ubuntu without a liveCD but windows7 doesn't work .. it asks me to repair my computer.. and another thing .. there's a "boot failed: some code i couldn't catch" before the grub menu appears.. why ??

Comment: boot-repair will not install on 12.10 Beta 1.  However, the second solution did work for me on 12.10 B1.

Comment: Thank you this worked.  (I spent a long time trying the dedicated "boot-repair-disk" which never worked.)