# Upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 on Windows 7 Dual Boot - Now, no boot!

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GRUB complains of “no such partition” after installing 12:04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125428/grub-complains-of-no-such-partition-after-installing-1204)

My HP Pavilion All-in-One pc has a dual boot with the original Windows 7 Home premium dual booted with Ubuntu 11.10. Whilst booted in Ubuntu I upgraded to 12.04 and whilst everything seemed to install OK when it was finished and rebooted I was not presented with the normal grub screen but with a 'GNU GRUB version 1.99-21ubuntu3' screen that gave me options to Linux 3.2.0-23generic-pae and several others including 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)'. However, regardless of which option I choose it comes back with
'error: no such partition'

I assume that the GRUb is pointing to the wrong place or corrupt. Any ideas how to rectify this and get me back to a bootable system?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience when upgrading. The OS selection screen had a black background instead of the usual purple and everything (including dropping down to the command line) simply caused the error "error: no such partition" to be printed again.

What I did was to use [`boot-repair`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). You can read the detailed instructions from that link, but the gist of it is to burn a Live CD or USB, boot into that and run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

in a terminal, which will install and `boot-repair`. Then follow the instructions and you should be good to go.

Comment: I also use this method

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with grub 2, I'd recommend installing grub legacy, and it should find all your OS and partitions automatically.

If you are not sure how to do it, read this tutorial:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1298932

gl