# Boot error > no such device: grub rescue

Tags: grub2, system-installation

After an installation of Ubuntu 12.04, erasing an old partition with Ubuntu 10.10, I can't get grub to load. I can't access my Windows 7 partition either

I get the message:

```
> error: no such device: 58ABF29C...  
grub rescue>
```

I suppose my master boot record got erased/corrupted. How can I check and fix this?

Comment: If your MBR were erased, GRUB would not run at all.  What is happening here is that the MBR code is running, and has been told to look on the partition with the UUID of 58abf29c... for the configuration menu.  Most likely, this was the partition you erased, so it doesn't exist anymore.  The easiest way to fix it would be to download the [grub boot repair CD](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/), which will probably fix it automatically.

Comment: A complete answer is here http://askubuntu.com/questions/125428/grub-complains-of-no-such-partition-after-installing-1204

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Re-install your GRUB.

1. Boot using a live cd of ubuntu.
2. Open a terminal and run the command
   `sudo fdisk -l`
   It lists the complete partition table of the hard disk. In there, identify which partition you have got your linux installed on. You can identify it using the drive size you had allocated for it and looking at the last column of the output which will be `extended` or `Linux` for all of your linux partitions. The partition will most probably be something like `/dev/sda5` or something. Remember this partition.
3. Create a temporary folder in your home directory (Note: You can make the temporary folder anywhere you want. I’m using the home folder just for the sake of explanation). I’m calling it `temp` for now. So that `temp folder’s path will be`/home/ubuntu/temp`.
4. Mount your linux partition there. That is, assuming that you found your linux partition to be `/dev/sda5`, you mount that at the `temp` folder by doing the following command

   `sudo mount /dev/sda5 /home/ubuntu/temp`
5. If you want to check whether you have mounted the correct partition, go to your home folder and open temp. You will be in the `/` directory. In there you will find `home`, in which your home folder’s name will be there. Once you’ve confirmed you have mounted the correct partition, do step 6.
6. You have to install grub by showing the system where to read the data from the hard disk at the beginning. Don’t worry, just run the following command

   `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/home/ubuntu/temp /dev/sda`

   The `/dev/sda` corresponds to your hard disk name. Replace it by whatever the command `sudo fdisk -l` command showed you.
7. You’re done. You may restart your system.

Comment: wnen I run the mount command I get the following error:
mount: you must specify the filesystem type

Comment: I did sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /home/ubuntu/temp, the partition appeared as "Extended" with fdisk -l

Comment: 1. Are you sure sdb is is your hard disk's name? Confirm that. 2. /dev/sdb2 might be your logical partition container and not the partition in which you installed '/'. So try sdb3 or an other partitions that you have on your system.

Comment: /dev/sdb2 is marked as Boot and appears with filesystem "Extended" in fdisk -l

Comment: /dev/sdb is plausible too, as it has 40 GB, but it doesn't specify "Extended" or is marked as boot, when I try to mount /dev/sdb I get: mount: /dev/sdb already mounted or /home/ubuntu/temp busy

Comment: /dev/sdb7 appears with System "Linux", not "Extended" and allowed me to mount it..

Comment: Cool. Check the contents inside it. If you find the folders 'var', 'boot', etc in there, then that's what we need.

Comment: On the command sudo grub-install --root-directory=/home/ubuntu/temp /dev/sda

There's a space between temp*space*/dev/sda, is that space intentional or a typo? Does it matter?

Comment: That space is needed!

Comment: /usr/sbin/grub-setup: error: will not proceed with blocklists :(

Comment: That is weird. I'm reaching my limit here I guess. Do refer to the following. It might help you: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1769391

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem while upgrading 10.10 to 12.04 on an ASUS EEEPC.

Previously, I had **`/`** mounted on the 4GB disk and **`/home`** on the 12GB disk.  The latest Ubuntu needs at least 4.8GB in **`/`**, so I needed to swap the mount points.

I fixed the problem by changing the hard-disk boot sequence in my BIOS settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem when I created my /boot as a RAID 1 mirror on Mint 13.

Solved, by using the install CD to boot back into the system. Then re-mount my drives and chroot into the installed system:

```
apt-get install mdadm lvm2
```

Not sure if this is really needed but I then did:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install /dev/sdb
update-grub
```