# Error: no such device grub rescue

Tags: 12.04, grubrescue, boot-repair

Summary:

1. I keep getting the error: no such device grub rescue, after installing 12.04 (erasing an old 12.04 installation beforehand, but using the old /home mount, from a different HDD)
2. I have two HDD 80 GB (used for /) and 250 GB (used for /home)
3. I have tried [Boot error > no such device: grub rescue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143667/boot-error-no-such-device-grub-rescue) and also using live cd then installing boot-repair, none of them solves the problem.
4. Details from boot-repair: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1155292/

Question:

1. I have tried a fresh install several time, and during these times, the two HDD mounted differently. I mean sometimes the 80 GB mounted as sda, sometimes as sdb. is this normal?
2. Do you good guys at the Ask Ubuntu have any other way?

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes this is normal. This random change happens with some computers.
2. Try inverting the 2 hard disks in the BIOS boot order.

Comment: I think the problem is on the 80gigs HDD. I used the 250 gigs HDD instead and it works like a charm. thanx.