# How to make a good partition?

Tags: partitioning, grubrescue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)
>   [Boot error > no such device: grub rescue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143667/boot-error-no-such-device-grub-rescue)

I installed Ubuntu and everything was going fine, then one day, suddendly, at the start-up it was written: "error: no such device grub rescue". No way to do anything.

How can I fix this?

Comment: ^ Closer, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Boot with a Ubuntu live CD and check your hard drive and review partition table for problems. If the hd had not damage, you can reinstall GRUB to boot your system.  Is there a damage try to save all your data and replace hd.