# Grub rescue rescue error on boot even after trying a "Boot Repair"

Tags: 12.04, boot, system-installation, grubrescue

I tried to load Ubuntu 12.04 onto an old machine from a CD and the installation went fine, but I got the boot error: no such device: grub rescue.

I looked into the issue  with a CD live boot (unsure of the terminology, but I selected the option to try Ubuntu Desktop) and found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581099) forum post suggesting a Boot Repair program. I installed it from the terminal. I ran the program, it said it was fixed, and I tried to start it up no no avail. It gave me an [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6912880/) and to ask if I had any troubles.

What should I try now to fix this?

I am not very educated in programming or Linux type operating systems yet. But I would appreciate any help and will try to give as much information as necessary.

So far the only way my access desktop is using the installation disk.

Comment: May I ask what was the previous operating system installed on the computer? how did you exactly installed (by partitioning or similar)?... etc

Comment: The previous operating system was Windows XP Home Service Pack 3. The way I installed was by burning a CD and booting the system through the boot menu with the CD-ROM drive. I told the installer to remove Windows XP and to install only Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: have you tried http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows ?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall GRUB using the live CD.

Steps are available here: [Boot error > no such device: grub rescue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143667/boot-error-no-such-device-grub-rescue)

Comment: It said that it finished the installation, but upon restart I encountered the same error.