# Trying install OS on SSD but "Erro: no such device d7a2c..."

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

On HD left the `/home` directory, while the SSD (which was installed in place of the CD-ROM drive) left the `/` and the `swap area`. The first error was *"No such partition"*, put live-usb, ran the boot-repair and now the error is another: *"Error: no such device d7a2c..."*, it is almost sure that the computer is trying to find the files on the hard drive (which must be setted as principal) but like none he gives this error message. But in BIOS I do not know where switch to SSD to be the main.

Already tried this https://askubuntu.com/a/143668 but wasn't successful.

Notebook: Dell Inspiron N5010

Boot-repair log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9677083/

Comment: Some systems will not boot from a drive in the CD/DVD caddy.  Does yours? If not you may just have to create a /boot on the hard drive. The / (root) can still be on SSD in caddy. Or swap drives, so SSD is main drive and hard drive is in caddy.

Comment: @oldfred I do not know, but in the BIOS have the option to boot from the CD-ROM/DVD-ROM, I tried but I get the same error.

Comment: Still do not know if you can boot, CD/DVD boot a totally different way from drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I helped Filipe do the initial install.

/home is sda1 (hard drive)

swap is on sdb1 and root on sdb2  (both the ssd)

I have gotten the original grub error -- and re-installing grub usually solves it.   But I have no experience with ssd.

My guess is something in the bios is preventing it from booting from the ssd.

I always thought that an ssd would look like just another hard drive.

Well Filipe, I am not opposed to helping you install this on the hard drive at a later date.  Let's see if someone can help fix this.

sda is not marked bootable -- but sdb -- the ssd was when he installed the system.  COuld that be an issue?  I have not had issues with sdb being root.   Maybe it just wants the boot info on sda?  If so that is easy to fix.

http://pkill-9.com/recovering-ubuntudebian-linux-after-a-windows-installhiccup/

Wayno

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. This is not a forum. So, when you have additional information to share, it should be posted as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: Sri, or edit the question with more details