# No option to boot Ubuntu in GRUB

Tags: boot, 16.04, live-usb, bootloader, udev

let me first say, I'm am recently learning ubuntu. I had it install and everything was fine. I was trying to find a file that udev should have generated but could not find it. I ,dumbly, uninstalled udev and broke stuff. To fix it I ran `sudo apt-get -f upgrade` . Which did nothing really but let me reinstall udev. Once installed I looked for the file and didn't see it. I thought that mabey if I restart the laptop it will generate. Well, it booted up in memtest86 what ever that was and I spamed the escape key until I left memtest, restarted PC, booted to grub loader and in the grub the only options have to boot from are memtest86 and memtest terminal. No ubuntu option. It's still there though, I booted from a live disk and looked and all of my files are still there. How do I run a system repair or something to let me boot back to it?

Comment: You may want to check out this link for your problem with grub: [http://askubuntu.com/q/143667/570330](http://askubuntu.com/q/143667/570330)

Comment: I'm going to try that

Comment: Didn't work, nothing changed

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using boot-repair tool?
If not, here are steps.

1. Boot your system using a live Ubuntu cd.
2. Open a terminal and type following commands.

   `sudo -s`

   `apt-add-repository ppa: yannubunbtu/boot-repair`

   `apt-get update`

   `apt-get install boot-repair`

   `exit`

   `boot-repair`
3. Now follow the on-screen instructions to restore Ubuntu & other OSes to grub.

Comment: How would I do this from fedora 17 (or 20) live? That's all I can find disks too

Comment: Ok I downloaded ubuntu 10.04 from my storage server. I booted in to live and ran the 2nd command and it said "error: can't find signing_key_fingerprint at http://launchpad.net/API/1.0/~yannubunbtu/+archive/boot-repair"

Comment: The support for 10.04 has ended in 2015. I dont think that repositories for 10.04 may be available. Perhaps that is why you are getting this error. You might need to use 14.04 or 16.04 as they are the currently supported versions

Comment: Ok I tried it and it hang on the final stage for an hour now and no more progress.

Comment: It has been about 8 hours now, still says the same thing (purging kernels) how do I fix this now?

Comment: 24 hours and the same screen, "purge kernels then reinstall last kernel sda1 (ins). This may require several minutes"

Comment: It might be that the process has hanged up.... Just kill the process and retry

Comment: Retried 4 times now, return live CD 2 times and downloaded each two times