# Backup Ubuntu from live disk?

Tags: 16.04, live-usb, backup, live-cd, boot-repair

is there a way to back up all of my data from a live disk? I just need my installed programs and files. My grub messed up and I'm just starting over. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800889/no-option-to-boot-ubuntu-in-grub) is the link to the issue I had for more details. I am willing to do anything at this point. Thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you just boot via the live disk, mount your /home partition and copy your data to an external source. Once you boot intro the live disk (presuming you will use ubuntu) a hdd icon will show up in unity (ore more depending you your configuration) just click on that and it should mount it for you, that represents your hdd(s)

Comment: Will this transfer my download programs (Katoolin tools)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by downloaded, if you have that  the already  installed, no, it's more complex. If you only have some .deb files (the installer) then yes.

Comment: I have alot of things from "apt-get ..."