# Invisible Ubuntu after installing on second HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I recently bought a new SSD drive to my notebook. I placed the new device in the place of old HDD and old HDD replaced the DVD drive. BIOS sees it like:
Fixed HDD: new SSD drive
SATA ODD: old HDD
I want to say in advance that I cannot change the order of booting this drives. I made clean installation of Windows 10 on SSD. HDD was to be a drive for Ubuntu and Windows' data. I downloaded the lastest Ubuntu iso and I burnt it on pendrive.

Being in the Ubuntu installer, I formatted HDD drive and I created 200 GB size partition for "/" and 8 GB for SWAP. Ubuntu seemed to be ok with that and installation went along. Unfortunately, after rebooting I was welcomed with such a screen:

```
error: no such device: 9cac74d4-5015-46fd-b556-d66d146b63ba,
Entering rescue mode..
grub rescue>
```

ls command gave this output:

```
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1)
grub rescue>
```

So, there was only Windows' partitions listed. I started googling and I have found some guides like:
[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

[Boot error > no such device: grub rescue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143667/boot-error-no-such-device-grub-rescue)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1549194

But advices there did not help. The only good thing I found was:

```
sudo apt-get install lilo
sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr
```

It allowed me to repair MBR and run Windows 10. Ubuntu looks like installed - when I am using live distribution from Ubuntu, I can see the correct structure on chosen partition. I also tried to install Fedora 24 because I thought it may be some problem specific for Ubuntu, but no, the problem is quite universal.